# QR code and question mark symbol

Tags: php, qr-code, barcode

I'm implementing a PHP script to generate QR codes. I was reading the  encoding details here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_code

and to my surprise the question mark (`?`) and ampersand (`&`) symbols are not included in the list of the valid character. How can it be given that QR codes can be used to encode URLs? (URLs can have such characters).

It works perfectly, but of course I cannot encode URLs like:

`http://www.mywebsite.com/index.php?id=12`

see the question mark on the URL above?

Comment: maybe they just left those out, who knows. Was there a coding problem? what doesn't work?

Comment: it works perfectly, but of course I cannot encode URLs like www.mywebsite.com/index.php?id=12

Comment: can you edit your question as to the present results you're getting and for each of those characters? I added your comment to it in an edit, but the question will require clarification/details. Also make sure you did use the `http://` prefix and/or `https://`

Comment: well done thanks. I think it's pretty self explanatory: if the URL has a ? or a & it will not be encoded by a valid string of the QR code

Comment: *prego* - the answer may very well be that you need to `urlencode` it http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php @GianlucaGhettini

Comment: I tried to generate URL link including question mark and could generate QR code on online service. So this has to be possible

Comment: `$url = 'http://www.mywebsite.com/index.php?id=12'; $encoded = urlencode($url);` then use that in your qr generation. Where are we with the question? This is the solution here. @GianlucaGhettini you need to ping one of us just as I did here, as I may not stay here for very much longer and to see further developments.

Comment: @Fred-ii- looks like this is a solution. urlencode the string. Please post an answer and I'll accept it

Comment: @GianlucaGhettini there was no comment for too long so I closed the question with a duplicate. thanks for the offer though, *ciao* e grazie.